# How to make pandas' timedeltas timezone aware?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

If I do

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime("2020-03-08") + pd.to_timedelta('1D')
```

I get `Timestamp('2020-03-09 00:00:00')` as expected.

But when I try with a timezone aware datatype..

```
pd.to_datetime("2020-03-08").tz_localize('America/New_York') + pd.to_timedelta('1D')
```

I get `Timestamp('2020-03-09 01:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')` which is one hour after midnight.

This actually makes sense when you realise that 2020-03-08 is the day the clocks move forward for daylight savings time, and the day is only 23 hours long. But I have a use case where I want a time delta that is always one "local time" day long.

So is there a way of creating a "local time aware" timedelta object so that '1D' represents a calendar day whether the day is 23, 24 or 25 hours long?

Comment: You could localize *after* adding the timedelta: `(pd.to_datetime("2020-03-08") + pd.to_timedelta('1D')).tz_localize('America/New_York')`

Comment: That works, but in the broader context of the code I'm working on gives undesirable behavior  when I'm working with hourly time-series. Anytime I'm working with time I feel my head is going to explode.

Comment: Thinking this through once more, there seems to be another problem: e.g. 2020-3-7 in EST will have 2 am while 2020-3-8 does not due to the transition to EDT. So adding 1 day will work in UTC/naive but localization will fail.

Comment: Yes, datetimes are smart enough to handle such problems, and I was hoping that there was a way to make timedeltas similarly smart so I didn't have to think about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is compare the `.dst()` attributes of the timestamps and adjust by 1 hour if a DST transition falls in between. You will also have to catch the case where adding the timedelta would cause the resulting timestamp to fall exactly on an hour that is non-existent in the timezone.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz

def account_for_dst(t0, t1):
    """
    adjust the timedelta between two timezone-aware timestamps t0 and t1
    for DST transitions.
    """
    # check if time delta would fall exactly on a DST transition:
    dt = t1-t0
    try:
        _ = (t0.tz_localize(None)+dt).tz_localize(t0.tz)
    except pytz.NonExistentTimeError:
        return t0, t1 # t0 and t1 not modified...
    
    # otherwise, adjust the time delta...
    else:
        if t0.dst() > t1.dst():
            t1 += pd.to_timedelta('1H')
        elif t0.dst() < t1.dst():    
            t1 -= pd.to_timedelta('1H')
        return t0, t1
```

That would give exemplary results like

```
times = ("2020-3-7 02:00", "2020-3-8 00:00", "2020-11-1 00:00")

for t in times:
    t0 = pd.to_datetime(t).tz_localize('America/New_York')
    t1 = t0 + pd.to_timedelta('1D')
    print(f"before: {str(t0), str(t1)}")
    t0, t1 = account_for_dst(t0, t1)
    print(f"after: {str(t0), str(t1)}\n")   
    
# before: ('2020-03-07 02:00:00-05:00', '2020-03-08 03:00:00-04:00')
# after: ('2020-03-07 02:00:00-05:00', '2020-03-08 03:00:00-04:00')

# before: ('2020-03-08 00:00:00-05:00', '2020-03-09 01:00:00-04:00')
# after: ('2020-03-08 00:00:00-05:00', '2020-03-09 00:00:00-04:00')

# before: ('2020-11-01 00:00:00-04:00', '2020-11-01 23:00:00-05:00')
# after: ('2020-11-01 00:00:00-04:00', '2020-11-02 00:00:00-05:00')
```